# Why monitoring a keyboard interrupt in python thread doesn't work

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a very simple python code:

```
def monitor_keyboard_interrupt():

  is_done = False 

  while True:
    if is_done
      break
    try:
      print(sys._getframe().f_code.co_name)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
      is_done = True

def test():
  monitor_keyboard_thread = threading.Thread(target = monitor_keyboard_interrupt)
  monitor_keyboard_thread.start()
  monitor_keyboard_thread.join()

def main():
  test()

if '__main__' == __name__:
  main()
```

However when I press 'Ctrl-C' the thread isn't stopped. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try moving the while loop inside the try block.

Comment: @piedar It didn't work.

Comment: Because threads cannot listen to signals; only the main thread can.

Comment: @JamesMills Thanks for the help. I didn't know that. I've tested my code my listening in to the interrupt in the main thread and it worked.

Comment: No problems! See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple reason:

> Because only the **`<_MainThread(MainThread, started 139712048375552)>`** can create signal handlers and listen for signals.

This includes `KeyboardInterrupt` which is a SIGINT.

THis comes straight from the [signal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) docs:

> Some care must be taken if both signals and threads are used in the
>   same program. The fundamental thing to remember in using signals and
>   threads simultaneously is: always perform signal() operations in the
>   main thread of execution. Any thread can perform an alarm(),
>   getsignal(), pause(), setitimer() or getitimer(); only the main thread
>   can set a new signal handler, and the main thread will be the only one
>   to receive signals (this is enforced by the Python signal module, even
>   if the underlying thread implementation supports sending signals to
>   individual threads). This means that signals can’t be used as a means
>   of inter-thread communication. Use locks instead.